# Do port 80 listen request by default on GCP computed engine?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform

If I create an instance of the GCP computed engine and run docker of a NodeJS server and then map it to port 80 of the computed engine do I need to install nginx?

Comment: Is your server answer when you perform a local call on the port 80? (something like `curl localhost`)

Answer (score 1):

No, but you need to make sure, that you have firewall rules that allow http/https access to that instance.